# SQL Stored Procedure Incorrect syntax near '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When executing my stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I got an error on updating a DATETIME2 field: Incorrect syntax near '-'.

When inserting with a stored procudre to same table, everything works.
What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Excuting stored procedure:

```
USE [DataAccountancyDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @Id int

SELECT  @Id = 3

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spJournalPurchaseEntry_Update]
        @Id = @Id OUTPUT,
        @JournalPurchaseId = 1,
        @Date = 2019-12-30,
        @DocumentNumber = 2020007,
        @AccountingYearId = 3,
        @AccountingPeriodId = 2,
        @VATPeriodId = 1,
        @Comment = N'Test',
        @SupplierId = 1,
        @InvoiceAmount = 1000

SELECT  @Id as N'@Id'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I got following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

Line 12:

```
@Date = 2019-12-30
```

.

FYI My table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JournalPurchaseEntry]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [JournalPurchaseId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Date] DATETIME2 NOT NULL, 
    [DocumentNumber] INT NOT NULL, 
    [AccountingYearId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [AccountingPeriodId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [VATPeriodId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Comment] NVARCHAR(250) NULL, 
    [SupplierId] INT NULL, 
    [InvoiceAmount] MONEY NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_JournalPurchaseEntry_ToJournalPurchase] FOREIGN KEY ([JournalPurchaseId]) REFERENCES [JournalPurchase]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_JournalPurchaseEntry_ToAccountingYear] FOREIGN KEY ([AccountingYearId]) REFERENCES [AccountingYear]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_JournalPurchaseEntry_ToAccountingPeriod] FOREIGN KEY ([AccountingPeriodId]) REFERENCES [AccountingPeriod]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_JournalPurchaseEntry_ToVATPeriod] FOREIGN KEY ([VATPeriodId]) REFERENCES [VATPeriod]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_JournalPurchaseEntry_ToClient] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [Supplier]([Id])
)
```

My stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spJournalPurchaseEntry_Update]
    @Id INT OUTPUT,
    @JournalPurchaseId INT, 
    @Date DATETIME2, 
    @DocumentNumber INT, 
    @AccountingYearId INT, 
    @AccountingPeriodId INT, 
    @VATPeriodId INT, 
    @Comment NVARCHAR(250), 
    @SupplierId INT, 
    @InvoiceAmount MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.JournalPurchaseEntry 
    SET
        JournalPurchaseId = @JournalPurchaseId, 
        [Date] = @Date, 
        DocumentNumber = @DocumentNumber, 
        AccountingYearId = @AccountingYearId, 
        AccountingPeriodId = @AccountingPeriodId, 
        VATPeriodId = @VATPeriodId, 
        Comment = @Comment, 
        SupplierId = @SupplierId, 
        InvoiceAmount = @InvoiceAmount

    WHERE [Id] = @Id;
END
```

Comment: The error is telling you where to look. Line 9 is `@Date = 2019-12-30,` That's an expression containing 3 integers. It should be a literal `varchar`.

Comment: @Date = '2019-12-30' and it will work, even if it is not varchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to pass the parameter in quotes

@Date = '2019-12-30'

Comment: Or even better use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD and pass '20191230'